# Envio de formulário

Tags: cakephp

Estou tentando ao enviar um formulário de contato, que utiliza o model "Contato", salvar os dados, porém, ele nem entra no:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->Contato->save($this->data)
}
```

Da o seguinte erro:

"Tentativa de acessar método privado na classe
Erro: A tabela users para o model User não foi encontrada.".

Sendo que o model de contato, não tem ligação nenhuma com usuários, e nem estou utilizando nada referente a usuários também.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, o component Auth, utilizado para o admin, estava causando este conflito, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
if (!isset($this->params['admin']) || !$this->params['admin']) {
    $this->Auth->enabled = false;
    $this->Auth->allow('*');
}

if (!empty($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == "admin") {
    $this->Auth->enabled = true;
```

Inclui "$this->Auth->enabled = false", e consegui trabalhar com o $this->data normalmente.